# How does VectorSlicer work in Spark 2.0?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

In the Spark official documentation,

> VectorSlicer is a transformer that takes a feature vector and outputs a new feature vector with a sub-array of the original features. It is useful for extracting features from a vector column.

- Does this select the important features from the set of features?
- If that is the case how is it done without the mention of a dependent variable?

I am trying to perform data clustering and I need the important features which will contribute to the clusters better. Can I use `VectorSlicer` for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does this select the important features from the set of features?

It doesn't. It literally slices the vector to select only specified indices.

> and need the important features which will contribute to the clusters better.

- If you have categorical data consider using [ChiSqSelector](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#chisqselector).
- Otherwise you can use dimensionality reduction like [PCA](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#pca). It won't be the same as feature selection but should provide similar benefits (keep only the most important signals, discard the rest).

Comment: I have up-voted your answer but if you can please explain your second point on dimension reduction in feature importance selection. I'm not sure the OP will get that point (and for other reader too)

Comment: @eliasah Edited as requested.